# What means .0 dp in android?

Tags: android, xml, density-independent-pixel

For example textview with size 33.0 dp in xml. It means double number or it has other features?

Comment: `dp` / `dip` = Density Independent Pixels, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-of-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android

Comment: `dp` is telling Android that the number you gave is in `Density Pixels`, which allows you to use a floating point number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're referring to either layout_width or layout_height; in this case these numbers are always floating point.  The ".0" on the end has no particular significance.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#layout_width for more information.